# My stylesheet isn't linking to my HTML

Tags: html, css

Really new to HTML & CSS but have created sites in the past and linked the CSS to the HTML quite easily. I can't understand where I'm going wrong (although I am sure it's massively obvious!) Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Katgrog</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My first try at my own website">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Does your css folder actually contain your stylesheets and the path is correct?

Comment: There's nothing terribly wrong with the code you've shown.  What's the actual problem?  When the browser requests the style sheet, what is the server's response?

Comment: check your F12 developer tool bar, likely under network, to see if those CSS files are coming is as 404 (bad lnks).

Comment: Hi - thanks for the help! Yeah the path is correct, have just checked the developer tool bar and it says the css files can't be found. I'm still pretty confused!

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Copy and paste it in your html, it will work. It seems you are forgetted to add slash(/) at the end before >.

Comment: If the problem was a missing `/` at the end, then there would be an obvious yellow screen of death error message… and then if you added it, there would be another warning message about there not being a stylesheet associated with the document because there is no `xmlns` attribute on the root element. The OP isn't using XML so the `/` is superfluous.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>you need to specify the `type`, so do something along these lines:</strike> (The type is not required)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Comment: "you need to specify the type" — This is not true

Comment: type is advisory only.   http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code i have tested in my local, it works fine

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa are you sure you are commenting on the right post?

Comment: I was thinking you were probably intending on commenting on the question, not my answer

Comment: yes, i was commenting on the question, i have created the HTML with above code with 2 css files with same folder structures. it is working fine for me

Comment: well you are still commenting on one of the answers :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62135/discussion-between-manjunath-siddappa-and-starvator).